# Jquery get element attribute and insert it to an input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help for this issue.
I have a list of file and in each one a checkbox input. So i need to check one of that checkboxes and when click on "Insert" button, get the attribute value and insert it to that text input.
I appreciate your help.

here is my html code link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qd3n5/4/

```
<div class="download_list">
    <div>
        <p class="name"> <a href="#" title="samle-image.gif" class="File_Name">samle-image.gif</a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="size-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="download_list">
    <div>
        <p class="name"> <a href="#" title="favicon.ico" class="File_Name">favicon.ico</a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="size-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="download_list">
    <div>
        <p class="name"> <a href="#" title="freedown.jpg" class="File_Name">freedown.jpg</a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="size-text">
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fileupload">
    <button type="button" id="Inser_btn" class="btn btn-primary Inser_btn"> <i class="UpIcon icon-remove"></i>
 <span>Insert</span>

    </button>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <input type="text" name="banners_image_local" value="some-text.png" size="51" maxlength="64">
</div>
```

Comment: share some code also to help you better

Comment: In future questions, please always include your code in the question. If jsfiddle was unavailable your original question would not have been answerable.

Comment: what is "the attribute value"? do you mean the checkbox value?

Comment: Actually i tried multiple time to include my code here but unfortunately it wasn't let me to do that. there is no some documentation to help adding code here. But thank alot for your help @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @AminJafari I mean the title attribute for a tag in p.class:name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$(function(){
    $('#Inser_btn').click(function(){
        var title='';
        $('input[name="delete"]:checked').each(function(){
            title+=$(this).closest('.size-text').prev().find('a').attr('title');
        });
        $('input[name="banners_image_local"]').val(title);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd3n5/12/)**

Answer (score 3):

Use this piece of Code

```
$("#Inser_btn").click(function(){
var val = $(".toggle:checked").parent().siblings().eq(0).find("p a").text();
$(".test input").val(val);
```

});

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/Qd3n5/15/)

Answer (score 3):

By doing so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Inser_btn').click(function(){
      $('.download_list').each(function(){
          var checked = $(this).find('.toggle');
          if(checked.is(':checked')){
            $('input[name="banners_image_local"]').val($(this).find('a').html());
            return false;
          }
      });
  });
});
```

[Here is a demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd3n5/20/)

Comment: Wow there is alot of nice answer. Thanks my friend it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

here is your code , have updated your JSFiddle 
used jQuery for doing this [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd3n5/21/)

```
$(function(){
$("button").on('click', function(){
    var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    if(checked.length >0)
    {
        var value = checked.val();
        $("input[name='banners_image_local']").val(value);    
    }

});
```

});

Comment: david : being glad to help you

Comment: Thanks my friend but unfortunately there is no option to do that, i think i have right to choose just one answer. sorry about that but for next time i will accept your answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this code works for you. Give it a try. (untested code)

```
$('#Inser_btn').on('click', function () {
   $('input[name="banners_image_local"]').val('');
   var ckText = $('input[name="delete"]:checked').val();
   var textBox = $('input[name="banners_image_local"]').val();
   textBox = textBox + " " + ckText;
   $('input[name="banners_image_local"]').val(textBox);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the checked checkboxes value in the input field this should do with jQuery:

```
$("#Inser_btn").click(function(){
    $("#banners_image_local").val("");
    $('input[name="delete"]:checked').each(function() {
        $("#banners_image_local").val($("#banners_image_local").val() + ($(this).attr('value')));
   });
});
```

Also set the input text to `id="banners_image_local"`

Best.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#Inser_btn').click(function () {
    $('input[name=banners_image_local]').val($('.toggle:checked').parent().prev().find('.File_Name').attr('title'));
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qd3n5/18/)**

Having a class name to input text would be better.